# How to call multiple function in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I am using, to call Modal which when the user clicks the particular button it will show a multiple dropdown button and while updating the button it will call the Modal to ask why and the user will insert some data and it will update.
**i am using a react Hooks.**

1.Main.js

**for updating the multiple button**

```
 const toggleMachine = (currentState, action) => {
    const nextState = machine.transition(currentState, action);
    if (currentState !== nextState.value) {
      send(ProjectStatus[nextState.value]);
      dispatch(updateTask({ ...projectEntity, status: ProjectStatus[nextState.value] }));
    }
  };
```

....

```
 <MachineModal
    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    open={open}
    onSubmit={() => toggleMachine(currentState)}
 />
```

2. MachineModal.js

**to get the Task details according to id**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getId = params.id;
    TaskHistoryApi.getTaskHistory(getId).then((response) => {
      setValues(response.data);
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        Notifier.error(error.response.data.title);
      });
  }, []);
```

**for updating the Tssk**

```
 const updateTaskHistory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
    ...
    };
    TaskHistoryApi.updateTaskHistories(data)
      .then((response) => {
        Notifier.success('Task History Updated Successfully');
        onClose();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Notifier.error(error.response.data.title);
      });
  };

 <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      fullWidth

    >
      <DialogTitle>
        Update Task History


      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          type="text"
          label="Project ID"
          fullWidth
          name="projectId"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={values.projectId}
          disabled
        />
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          type="text"
          label="Comment"
          fullWidth
          name="eventDetail"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={values.eventDetail}

        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button
          onClick={onClose}
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
        >
          Cancel

        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={updateTaskHistory}
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
        >
          Submit

        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
```

I have to update the Task History along with other stuff, so both need to be updated at the same time or vice versa, for now, it's updating only the Modal component not the Main.js

Comment: you aren't using React hooks or at least not in the code. can you show this please

Comment: kindly check i have updated the code @RedBaron

Comment: thanks for posting code but still not entirely sure on your issue. you just want to know how to run multiple functions using hooks?

Comment: yup that's the issue i want to call multiple function so that both get updated @RedBaron

Comment: just call `useEffect(() => function1() function2() )` that not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Effect hook executing on the change of the first state.

For example updating "other Stuff" when the task history changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //All functions that need to be triggered when 
   // "StateThatShouldTriggerThisEffect" changes
}, ["StateThatShouldTriggerThisEffect"])
```

Comment: it's not about changing, i know how to  watch the changes in array of dependencies, it's about calling multiple function  from parent to child